# Is it possible to enforce a python package to be installed before a dependency is with setuptools?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a dependency on a python source package (no wheels) that will build a c-extension with conditional features depending on whether or not it can detect `numpy` on the Python path (with an exception check on `import numpy` in their `setup.py`).

The key problem is I need to distribute a python package that *requires* these conditional `numpy` features which means ensuring `numpy` is available before the dependency I have is installed.

Concretely, I would like to be able to run the command `pip install my_package_name` and have the dependency installed with a guarantee that the c-extension of my dependency installed with `numpy` features enabled.

I do not know of a way to do this on a fresh environment without performing a separate initial install of `numpy`.

Is there anything I can do? If not is there something I should suggest to the maintainer of my python package dependency?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: It sounds like your title is inaccurate. You don't want to install your package before installing its dependency. You want to install one of your dependencies, `numpy`, before installing the other dependency.

Comment: Maybe not inaccurate but I can see how it might be misleading. It is a python package I want installed (numpy) before a dependency and it's not my own.

Comment: But you do depend on NumPy, transitively through your dependency on this package's optional features.

Comment: The closest thing to what you want I'm aware of is [optional dependencies](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies). Your non-NumPy dependency could declare an optional dependency on NumPy, and you could install it with the optional dependency. I'm not sure if that would guarantee the installation order you want, though, especially in cases where the package was previously installed without the optional dependency.

Comment: Yes that's true and the core of the question is having numpy installed and on the path before this dependency is built and installed. Listing numpy as a literal dependency in my python package does not change the outcome of my issue unfortunately. I'd be happy to rephrase the question but I cannot.

Comment: "*I do not know of a way to do this on a fresh environment without performing a separate initial install of `numpy`.*" Nope, no way. The only way is `pip install numpy && pip install my_package_name`